# Redirection through htaccess from non html to .html extension?

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to add .html to my html files automatically using htaccess.

As we can remove .html very easily but i want to know can i add `.html` to a non html file that is located with my website.
for example this is my domain

```
www.abc.com/name.html
```

but when i am accessing

```
www.abc.com/name
```

It is showing me the same page but not automatically adding the `.html` extension.

So i want that if i try to open
   `www.abc.com/name` then it automatically shows me `www.abc.com/name.html`

How to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://pcsmartcare.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: For which URL it doesn't work as you expected? Try giving as much details as possible so that I can help you better. Do you have any other .htaccess anywhere in your system OR any other rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
               

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]`

Comment: ok that is your existing code but for which URL my rule didn't work for you?

Comment: for all valid url's that i checked

Comment: I edited my answer to make this rule work both ways. Can you try edited code now.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to first put some effort yourself by explaining your problem clearly. You haven't yet replied to my earlier questions properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39415/discussion-between-neel-bhasin-and-anubhava)

Comment: try a new browser to test.

Comment: As I said this is fully tested and working code. If it doesn't work for you then you need to first comment out all other rules and see if this rule works in isolation first then start putting rest of rules back.